# Make a Solrnet Facet Linkeble with Solrnet?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, solr, solrnet

Im building a MVC4 application to make searches on a wiki document. Everything works great but i have not been able to figure out the best way to make the facets linkable.

i precent the facets on my startpage to make it easier to find keywords you look for:

```
             var products = solr.Query(SolrQuery.All,
                                  new QueryOptions {
                                      Rows = 0,
                                      Facet = new FacetParameters {
                                          Queries = new[] { new SolrFacetFieldQuery("products") }
                                      }
                                  });
        foreach(var facet in products.FacetFields["products"]) {
            var catagoryFacet = new CategoryFacet(facet.Key, facet.Value);
            facetProductList.Add(catagoryFacet);
        }
```

Then i loop through the list in the view like this:

```
<h2> Products: </h2>

@foreach (var facet in Model)
{
    foreach(var item in facet.products) {    
        <td><a href="http://localhost:5000/Home/FreeSearch?search=@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Name)">@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Name), @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Count)</a></td> <br/>
    }
```

But with this approach, when a user clicks the link what happen is that i send the word of facet back to the controller that fire of a search on that keyword since i know it exist.

I know this is kind of a bad way so i am trying to figure out a better way, and since im from sweden the link is broken if i use any of "åäö". It´s possible to handle by javascript but it feels very ugly, so how can i do this in a better way?

I have been looking at the the filter query but how do i make it linkable?

Regards
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by simply put Url.Encode on the Item.Name. Now the search works, as i wanted.

```
<h2> Products: </h2>

@foreach (var facet in Model)
{
    foreach(var item in facet.ProductFacets) {    
        <td><a href="http://localhost:5000/Home/FreeSearch?search=@Url.Encode(item.Name)">@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Name), @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Occurrences)</a></td> <br/>
    }
```